# How to complie the sass to css in sublime text3 when save sass file

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

How to complie the sass to css in sublime text3 when save sass file (ctrl +  s), How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sass​Builder package to compile the sass.
more info [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-text-compiling-sass/) and [package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SassBuilder).